# How return the count of number of occurrences of an integer in a vector, in a new vector using R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vector

New to R.  I have seen a lot of similar questions where tables are used to count the number of occurrences, but I want to create a new vector for each integer in vector_1 (e.g. 1 through 10,), where the number of occurrences of the integer in vector_1 is checked in vector_2, and then returned in a third vector_3.

Desired Result:

```
vector_1 <- c(1:10)
vector_2 <- c(3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10)
vector_3 <- c(0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

I have tried using for loops such as:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
for (j in vector_2) {
print(i) <- vector_3
}
}
```

Obviously this code doesn't work, but I am just not finding a good way to do a summation of the occurrences between the vectors.  Any guidance or alternate approaches would be welcomed.

*Edit: most all answers that I have seen to similar questions use tables to count the occurrences within vector_2; I haven't come across questions that compare the two vectors and then output the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make sense to me. Anyway, you can easily compare each value in vector 1 with each value in vector 2 using `outer`. `rowSums` then can give you the required counts.

```
vector_1 <- c(1:10)
vector_2 <- c(3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10)
rowSums(outer(vector_1, vector_2, "=="))
#[1] 0 0 1 2 1 0 1 0 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks this performs exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can create a factor variable:

```
vector_2 <- c(3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10)
vector_2 <- factor(vector_2,levels = 1:10)
table(vector_2)
```